# SSH command to list installed application bundles on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ssh, ios7, jailbreak

I want to be able to find a list installed applications on an iOS 7 device using SSH.  I have installed `open` to be able to launch them, but it requires the `com.application.identifier` bundle names to work.  Is there some centralized place that lists these identifiers?  If not, is there some command to extract them?  I have been looking for hours, but I everything I have found is for older iOS versions and outdated.

Comment: the application identifiers will be in the info.plist files. You just need to read those files to get the relevant information

Comment: @Petesh But is there some way to pull all of those out using just one line? (or a few)

Comment: I don't know the jailbroken environment (directory tree, commands), but if the find command is available, you can do something like: `find /Applications -name Info.plist -exec defaults read {} CFBundleIdentifier \;`

Comment: `defaults` is not an available command on iOS

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer.  I had to install Erica Utilities to get the `plutil` function.  Then I just used `find /User/Applications/ -name iTunesMetadata.plist -exec plutil -key softwareVersionBundleId {} \;`